# ¿Como puedo hacer que se esconda mi alerta dentro de un modal en Jquery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, django

Lo que pasa es que tengo un botón `Finalizar compra` que al darle `click` y no estar loggeado aparece una modal con el mensaje de alerta

> "Deberias darte de alta antes de continuar con tu compra"

y tengo otro botón en el `navbar`  de `carrito` que saca el mismo modal pero sin el mensaje de alerta, mi problema es que si primero le doy `click` al botón de `carrito` no me sale el mensaje y eso esta bien pero si le doy `click` al boton de `Finalizar compra` me aparece el modal con el mensaje de alerta y si cierro la modal y le doy `click` ahora al de `carrito` me sigue saliendo el mensaje de alerta y eso es lo que no quiero.

Mi HTML de la alerta es este:

```
<div class="modal signUpContent fade" id="ModalLogin" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog ">
    <div class="modal-content">

        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"> &times; </button>
            <h3 class="modal-title-site text-center"> Ingresa a {{ store.name }} </h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div id="kapps_modal_login" class="alert alert-danger" style="display: none;" shopping_cart_url="{% url "store_shopping_cart" %}">
                <strong>¡ATENCIÓN!</strong> <p>Date de alta o crea una cuenta para proceder con la compra.</p>
            </div>
                  .
                  .
                  .
```

y mi JQUERY es este:

```
    self.active_listener_kapps_alert = function(){
    $('#ModalLogin').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
        var shopping_cart_url = $('#kapps_modal_login').attr('shopping_cart_url');
        if(window.has_active_kapps && shopping_cart_url == window.location.pathname ) {
            $('#kapps_modal_login').show();
        }
    });
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Bueno nadie contesto mi pregunta pero encontré la solución modificando mi java script.

```
 self.active_listener_kapps_alert = function(){
    $('#ModalLogin').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
        var shopping_cart_url = $('#kapps_modal_login').attr('shopping_cart_url');
        if(window.has_active_kapps && shopping_cart_url == window.location.pathname ) {
            $('#kapps_modal_login').show().end();
        }
    });

    $('#ModalLogin').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
        window.has_active_kapps = false;
        $('#kapps_modal_login').hide();   
    });
};
```